# JsonArray post from Android to Laravel Rest Error

Tags: android, arrays, post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to post some data form android app to Laravel rest api. The data is converted and posted as jsonArray.

The code works fine in HttpRequester (Firefox extension) but throws 500 Internal Server Error when posted from Android.

**Android**

```
public static int check(String token) throws IOException
{
    int flag;
    String response=Constants.EMPTY_STRING;
    URL mUrl=null;
    HttpURLConnection mConnection=null;

    String message="";
    JSONObject myObject1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject myObject2 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject myObject3 = new JSONObject();

    JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject mySentObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        myObject1.put("id","01");
        myObject1.put("name","Ali Jibran");
        myObject1.put("date","2016-04-01");
        myArray.put(myObject1);
        myObject2.put("id","02");
        myObject2.put("name","Imran Raja");
        myObject2.put("date","2016-05-03");
        myArray.put(myObject2);
        myObject3.put("id","03");
        myObject3.put("name","M.Quddus Raja");
        myObject3.put("date","2015-06-01");
        myArray.put(myObject3);
        //mySentObject.put("data",myArray.toString());
        //message = mySentObject.toString();
        message = myArray.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //String mQuery = Constants.APP_TOKEN_KEY
    //        + Constants.EQUALS + token + Constants.AMPERSAND + "posted=" + message;
    String mQuery = "posted=" + message;

    Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG,"================== Checking =================" );
    Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, "check -> Query is : " +  mQuery);

    mUrl = new URL(Constants.APP_URL + "info?" + mQuery);
    mConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
    mConnection.setDoInput(true);
    mConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    //mConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(message.getBytes().length);
    mConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    mConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    mConnection.setRequestMethod(Constants.POST);

    mConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
    mConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    //Write Post Data

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(mConnection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeUTF(message.getBytes().toString());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    flag = mConnection.getResponseCode();
    if (flag != 200) {
        Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG,"Failure " + flag + " " + mConnection.getResponseMessage());
    }
    if (flag == 200){
        response = readData(mConnection);
        try
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if(jsonObject.has("reply"))
                Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG,"Reply received -> " + jsonObject.getString("reply"));
            if(jsonObject.has("newmercs"))
                Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG,"Data received -> " + jsonObject.getString("newmercs"));
            if(jsonObject.has("count"))
                Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG,"Count received -> " + jsonObject.getString("count"));
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

**Laravel 5.0**

```
 Route::post('info',function(){

//$newmercs = json_decode(Input::get('posted'),true);
$newmercs = json_decode(Input::get('posted'));
$reply = "";
$count = 0;

foreach ($newmercs as $newmerc){
    $count++;
}

if ($count > 0){
    $reply = 'Success';
}else {
    $reply = 'Failure';
}

return response()->json(compact('newmercs','reply','count'));
});
```

**This is what i should get (HttpRequester also returns the same)**

```
 {
"newmercs": 
[
{
"date": "2016-04-01",
"id": "01",
"name": "Ali Jibran"
},
{
"date": "2016-05-03",
"id": "02",
"name": "Imran Raja"
},
    {
        "date": "2015-06-01",
        "id": "03",
        "name": "M.Quddus Raja"
    }
],
"reply": "Success",
"count": ​3
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Retrofit Lib to communicate with your API, it's so much easier.

Retrofit doc : http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Have a great day

Comment: Thanks. but i am not looking for new api. just want to know the problem with existing code.

Comment: It's not a new API it's just a library to make call to an API like your Laravel request